# RSS reader and model (logic) layer in practise

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have written a logic part in my app. I'd like to learn best practices, so can you please check my class?

This class is a little too big in my opinion, but I have no idea what I should do now. I've pasted only the main class, but if you'd like to see anything related, please tell me.

This class is my logic in model layer.  I think it is correct, am I right?

```
using RssReader.DataAccessLayer;
using RssReader.DataAccessLayer.Repository;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Web;
using Windows.Web.Syndication;

namespace RssReader.Model.Logic
{
    public class FeedDataSource : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly SQLiteConnection _dbConnection;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        private readonly IRepository<FeedData> _feedDataRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<FeedItem> _feedItemRepository;
        private readonly RoamingSettings _roamingSettings;

        private readonly string _feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings;

        private bool _isDisposed;

        public FeedDataSource(string databaseName,
            string feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings)
        {
            this._dbConnection = InitializeDatabase(databaseName);
            this._unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(this._dbConnection);
            this._feedDataRepository = this._unitOfWork.GetFeedRepository<FeedData>();
            this._feedItemRepository = this._unitOfWork.GetFeedRepository<FeedItem>();
            this._roamingSettings = new RoamingSettings();
            this._feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings = feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings;
        }

        public async Task<FeedData> AddFeedAsync(string feedLink)
        {
            return await this.AddFeedAsync(new Uri(feedLink));
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<FeedData>> GetFeedsAsync()
        {
            await this.CheckDatabaseIntegrity();

            IEnumerable<Uri> feedsLink = this.GetFeedsLinkFromRoamingSettings()
                .Select(link => new Uri(link));

            IEnumerable<string> eTags = (await Task.WhenAll
                (
                feedsLink.Select(link => GetETagAsync(link))
                )).Where(eTag => !string.Equals(eTag, string.Empty));

            IEnumerable<FeedData> refreshedFeeds = await Task.WhenAll
                (
                this._feedDataRepository
                .Find(feed => !eTags.Contains(feed.ETag))
                .Select(this.RefreshFeedAsync)
                );

            IEnumerable<FeedData> feedsData = refreshedFeeds.Union(this._feedDataRepository.GetAll());
            foreach (FeedData feedData in feedsData.Except(refreshedFeeds))
            {
                var feedItems = this._feedItemRepository
                    .Find(feed => int.Equals(feed.FeedDataId, feedData.Id));

                foreach (FeedItem feedItem in feedItems)
                    feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
            }

            return feedsData;
        }

        public void DeleteFeed(string feedLink)
        {
            this.DeleteFeed(new Uri(feedLink));
        }

        public void SaveChanges()
        {
            this._unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public void RollbackChanges()
        {
            this._unitOfWork.Rollback();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private IEnumerable<string> GetFeedsLinkFromRoamingSettings()
        {
            object obj = this._roamingSettings
                .ReadValue(this._feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings);
            var collection = obj as IEnumerable<object> ?? Enumerable.Empty<object>();

            IEnumerable<string> feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings = Enumerable.Empty<string>();

            if (collection.Any())
                feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings = collection
                    .Select(feedLink => feedLink.ToString()).Cast<string>();

            return feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings;
        }

        private async Task CheckDatabaseIntegrity()
        {
            IEnumerable<Uri> feedsLinkFromDatabase =
                this._feedDataRepository.GetAll().Select(feed => feed.Link);
            IEnumerable<Uri> feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings =
                this.GetFeedsLinkFromRoamingSettings().Select(link => new Uri(link));

            var matches = feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings.Except(feedsLinkFromDatabase);

            await Task.WhenAll
                (
                matches.Select(this.AddFeedAsync)
                );

            matches = feedsLinkFromDatabase.Except(feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings);
            foreach (Uri feedLink in matches)
                this.DeleteFeed(feedLink);
        }

        private async Task<FeedData> AddFeedAsync(Uri feedLink)
        {
            var matches = this._feedDataRepository.Find(feed => Uri.Equals(feed.Link, feedLink));
            if (matches.Any())
            {
                FeedData feedDataFromDatabase = matches.Single();
                feedDataFromDatabase.Error = FeedError.FeedAlreadyExist;

                return feedDataFromDatabase;
            }

            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task<string> eTag = GetETagAsync(feedLink, cts);
            FeedData feedData = await RetrieveFeedAsync(feedLink);

            if (feedData == null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                return new FeedData { Error = FeedError.DownloadFeedError };
            }

            ICollection<string> feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings =
                this.GetFeedsLinkFromRoamingSettings().ToList();
            if (!feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings
                .Where(link => string.Equals(link, feedLink.ToString())).Any())
            {
                feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings.Add(feedLink.ToString());
                this._roamingSettings.AddOrUpdateValue
                    (
                    this._feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings,
                    feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings.ToArray()
                    );
            }

            feedData.ETag = await eTag;

            this._feedDataRepository.Add(feedData);
            foreach (FeedItem feedItem in feedData.Items)
            {
                feedItem.FeedDataId = feedData.Id;
                this._feedItemRepository.Add(feedItem);
            }

            return feedData;
        }

        private async Task<FeedData> RefreshFeedAsync(FeedData oldfeedData)
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            Task<string> eTag = GetETagAsync(oldfeedData.Link, cts);
            FeedData feedData = await RetrieveFeedAsync(oldfeedData.Link);

            if (feedData == null)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                oldfeedData.Error = FeedError.DownloadFeedError;
                return oldfeedData;
            }

            feedData.Id = oldfeedData.Id;
            feedData.Category = oldfeedData.Category;
            feedData.Order = oldfeedData.Order;
            feedData.ETag = await eTag;

            this._feedDataRepository.Update(feedData);

            var feedsToRemove = this._feedItemRepository
                .Find(feed => int.Equals(feed.FeedDataId, feedData.Id))
                .Except(feedData.Items, FeedComparer<FeedItem>.Instance)
                .ToList();

            foreach (FeedItem feedItem in feedsToRemove)
                this._feedItemRepository.Remove(feedItem);

            var feedsToAdd = feedData.Items.Except
                (
                this._feedItemRepository
                .Find(feed => int.Equals(feed.FeedDataId, feedData.Id)),
                FeedComparer<FeedItem>.Instance
                )
                .ToList();

            foreach (FeedItem feedItem in feedsToAdd)
            {
                feedItem.FeedDataId = feedData.Id;
                this._feedItemRepository.Add(feedItem);
            }

            return feedData;
        }

        private void DeleteFeed(Uri feedLink)
        {
            ICollection<string> feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings =
                this.GetFeedsLinkFromRoamingSettings().ToList();
            if (feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings
                .Where(link => string.Equals(link, feedLink.ToString())).Any())
            {
                feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings.Remove(feedLink.ToString());
                this._roamingSettings.AddOrUpdateValue
                    (
                    this._feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings,
                    feedsLinkFromRoamingSettings.ToArray()
                    );
            }

            int feedDataId = this._feedDataRepository
                .Find(feed => Uri.Equals(feed.Link, feedLink))
                .Select(feed => feed.Id).SingleOrDefault();

            this._feedDataRepository.RemoveById(feedDataId);

            IEnumerable<FeedItem> feedItems = this._feedItemRepository.GetAll()
                .Where(feed => int.Equals(feed.FeedDataId, feedDataId)).ToList();

            foreach (FeedItem feedItem in feedItems)
                this._feedItemRepository.Remove(feedItem);
        }

        private static SQLiteConnection InitializeDatabase(string databaseName)
        {
            string[] path ={ Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path,
                               databaseName };
            var dbConnection =
                new SQLiteConnection(System.IO.Path.Combine(path), true);
            dbConnection.CreateTable<FeedData>(CreateFlags.ImplicitPK |
                CreateFlags.AutoIncPK);
            dbConnection.CreateTable<FeedItem>(CreateFlags.AllImplicit |
                CreateFlags.AutoIncPK);

            return dbConnection;
        }

        public static async Task<FeedData> RetrieveFeedAsync(Uri feedLink)
        {
            var feed = new SyndicationFeed();
            var client = new SyndicationClient();
            var feedData = new FeedData();
            client.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
            client.BypassCacheOnRetrieve = true;
            try
            {
                feed = await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(feedLink);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                SyndicationErrorStatus syndicationError = SyndicationError.GetStatus(e.HResult);
                if (syndicationError == SyndicationErrorStatus.Unknown)
                {
                    WebErrorStatus webError = WebError.GetStatus(e.HResult);

                    if (webError == WebErrorStatus.Unknown)
                        throw;
                }

                return null;
            }

            if (feed.Title != null && feed.Title.Text != null)
                feedData.Title = feed.Title.Text;

            if (feed.Subtitle != null && feed.Subtitle.Text != null)
                feedData.Description = feed.Subtitle.Text;

            feedData.Link = feedLink;

            if (feed.Items != null && feed.Items.Any())
            {
                // Use the date of the latest post as the last updated date
                feedData.PubDate = feed.Items.First().PublishedDate.DateTime;

                foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
                {
                    FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
                    if (item.Title != null && item.Title.Text != null)
                        feedItem.Title = item.Title.Text;

                    if (item.PublishedDate != null)
                        feedItem.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;

                    if (item.Authors != null && item.Authors.Any())
                        feedItem.Author = item.Authors.First().Name;

                    if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Atom10)
                    {
                        if (item.Content != null && item.Content.Text != null)
                            feedItem.Content = item.Content.Text;

                        if (item.Id != string.Empty)
                            feedItem.Link = new Uri(item.Id);
                    }
                    else if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Rss20)
                    {
                        if (item.Summary != null && item.Summary.Text != null)
                            feedItem.Content = item.Summary.Text;

                        if (item.Links != null && item.Links.Any())
                            feedItem.Link = item.Links.First().Uri;
                    }

                    feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
                }
            }

            return feedData;
        }

        private static async Task<string> GetETagAsync(Uri feedLink,
            CancellationTokenSource cts = null)
        {
            const int millisecondsTimeout = 2500;

            if (cts == null)
                cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(feedLink);
            webRequest.Method = "HEAD";
            webRequest.Headers["UserAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)";

            Task<WebResponse> webResponse = WebRequestExtensions.GetResponseAsync(webRequest, cts.Token);
            try
            {
                if (await Task.WhenAny(webResponse,
                    Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)) == webResponse)
                {
                    using (var result = await webResponse)
                    {
                        return result.Headers["ETag"] ?? string.Empty;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    cts.Cancel();

                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!this._isDisposed)
                {
                    if (isDisposing)
                    {
                        if (this._dbConnection != null)
                            this._dbConnection.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                this._isDisposed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class WebRequestExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request,
            CancellationToken ct)
        {
            using (ct.Register(() => request.Abort(), useSynchronizationContext: false))
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
                    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                    return (WebResponse)response;
                }
                catch (WebException e)
                {
                    if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.RequestCanceled)
                        ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                        throw new TaskCanceledException(e.Message, e);

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your constructor has mixed concerns:

> ```
> public FeedDataSource(string databaseName,
>     string feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings)
> {
>     this._dbConnection = InitializeDatabase(databaseName);
>     this._unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(this._dbConnection);
>     this._feedDataRepository = this._unitOfWork.GetFeedRepository<FeedData>();
>     this._feedItemRepository = this._unitOfWork.GetFeedRepository<FeedItem>();
>     this._roamingSettings = new RoamingSettings();
>     this._feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings = feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings;
> }
> ```

These lines increase the *coupling* between `FeedDataSource` and other classes:

> ```
>     this._unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(this._dbConnection);
>     this._roamingSettings = new RoamingSettings();
> ```

If you have an *abstraction* for `UnitOfWork` and `RoamingSettings`, you should *inject* them as *dependencies* of your class:

> ```
> public FeedDataSource(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,
>                         IRoamingSettings roamingSettings,
>                         string feedsLinkSettingNameInRoamingSettings)
> {
>     _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
>     _roamingSettings = roamingSettings;
>     //...
> }
> ```

The `this` qualifier you're using, is redundant. If private fields have an underscore prefix, it's specifically to avoid having to use `this` to qualify a member. I would drop it, the code would be easier on the eyes.

I like that your private fields are `readonly`.

---

This method is calling a private overload:

> ```
> public async Task<FeedData> AddFeedAsync(string feedLink)
> {
>     return await this.AddFeedAsync(new Uri(feedLink));
> }
> ```

I wouldn't bother with the overload if it's not `public` - in other words, if the only way your client code can/should `AddFeedAsync` is by providing a `string`, then I'd merge the two methods into a single `public` member.

However I like that you have an overload that takes an `Uri` parameter, so I'd make that overload `public`, and move the method closer (just below) the other `AddFeedAsync` overload. Right now you have them completely separated, normally I'd expect a method and its overloads to be regrouped, to show up close to each other in the code file.

Same goes for `DeleteFeed`.

---

There's something about `RetrieveFeedAsync` that smells:

> ```
> foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
> {
>     FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
>     if (item.Title != null && item.Title.Text != null)
>         feedItem.Title = item.Title.Text;
>
>     if (item.PublishedDate != null)
>         feedItem.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;
>
>     if (item.Authors != null && item.Authors.Any())
>         feedItem.Author = item.Authors.First().Name;
>
>     if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Atom10)
>     {
>         if (item.Content != null && item.Content.Text != null)
>             feedItem.Content = item.Content.Text;
>
>         if (item.Id != string.Empty)
>             feedItem.Link = new Uri(item.Id);
>     }
>     else if (feed.SourceFormat == SyndicationFormat.Rss20)
>     {
>         if (item.Summary != null && item.Summary.Text != null)
>             feedItem.Content = item.Summary.Text;
>
>         if (item.Links != null && item.Links.Any())
>             feedItem.Link = item.Links.First().Uri;
>     }
>
>     feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
> }
> ```

You should always enclose a scope with `{}` braces, even if it's just for a single instruction. Also I would extract the `if...else` part into its own method, to reduce nesting; I think you could have a `SetFeedItemLinkAndContent(SyndicationItem item, FeedItem feedItem, SyndicationFormat format)` method, which would make the loop look like this:

```
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    FeedItem feedItem = new FeedItem();
    if (item.Title != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Title.Text))
    {
        feedItem.Title = item.Title.Text;
    }

    if (item.PublishedDate != null)
    {
        feedItem.PubDate = item.PublishedDate.DateTime;
    }

    if (item.Authors != null && item.Authors.Any())
    {
        feedItem.Author = item.Authors.First().Name;
    }

    SetFeedItemLinkAndContent(item, feedItem, feed.SourceFormat);

    feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
}
```

And the `SetFeedItemLinkAndContent` method could look like this:

```
private void SetFeedItemLinkAndContent(SyndicationItem item, 
                                       FeedItem feedItem, 
                                       SyndicationFormat format)
{
    string content = string.Empty;
    Uri link = string.Empty;

    switch (feed.SourceFormat)
    {
        case SyndicationFormat.Atom10:

            if (item.Content != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Content.Text))
            {
                content = item.Content.Text;
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Id))
            {
                link = new Uri(item.Id);
            }

            break;

        case SyndicationFormat.Rss20:

            if (item.Summary != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Summary.Text))
            {
                content = item.Summary.Text;
            }

            if (item.Links != null && item.Links.Any())
            {
                link = item.Links.First().Uri;
            }

            break;

        case default:

            throw new NotSupportedException("Unhandled SyndicationFormat value.");
    }

    feedItem.Content = content;
    feedItem.Link = link;
}
```

You may want to consider extending the `SyndicationItem` type with a `ToFeedItem` extension method to host this logic instead, which would further simplify this code:

```
foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
    var feedItem = item.ToFeedItem(feed.SourceFormat);
    feedData.Items.Add(feedItem);
}
```

---

Condition evaluations in C# are smarter than that. This:

> ```
> if (!this._isDisposed)
> {
>     if (isDisposing)
>     {
>         if (this._dbConnection != null)
>             this._dbConnection.Dispose();
>     }
> }
> ```

Is exactly the same as this:

```
if (!_isDisposed && isDisposing && _dbConnection != null)
{
    _dbConnection.Dispose();
}
```

`isDisposing` will not be evaluated if `!_isDisposed` evaluates to `false`, and `_dbConnection != null` will not be evaluated if any of the previous conditions already failed: don't nest 3 successive conditions 3 levels deep - make one condition with all 3 Boolean expressions instead.

---

Your class indeed has too many responsibilities. Normally a type that consumes a `UnitOfWork` does not care about the database stuff - the very idea of a unit of work / repository is to *abstract* the database connection away! By moving the instantiation of the unit of work outside the constructor like I recommended above (way above), you also remove `InitializeDatabase` from your class' concerns, and ask the code that instantiates a `FeedDataSource` to also instantiate a `UnitOfWork` - and since that code will be owning the database connection, you can probably also get rid of a lot of the `Dispose` logic (i.e. move it elsewhere).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was helpful ;) Btw should I keep extensions class in other file, or can I have it in the same file as main (FeedDataSource) class?